# Check for Android Content Uri

Tags: android, uri, android-contentprovider

I have two apps.  App B has a ContentProvider that App A can interact with.  App B is not required.  If I query for App B content I get this error when App B is not installed:

```
Unknown URL content://com.appb.provider
```

Now I know it works when App B exists and I didn't realize a query would crash if a provider wasn't there.  How are we supposed to check for custom providers before querying?  There's no obvious boolean check in ContentResolver and I think I could use:

```
getContentResolver().acquireContentProviderClient()
```

but that seems heavy handed.  Is there a better way to check that a provider is out there?

Answer (score 2):

I found a decent solution with:

```
getContentResolver().getType()
```

You can check for null and not have to worry about releasing a client.  Still open to better options.